# "key error" when using an enum as a dictionary key in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, enums

I want to use an enum as the key for a dictionary, but get a KeyError.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from enum import Enum, unique
from typing import List

@unique
class Color(Enum):
    RED = "cherry"
    GREEN = "cucumber"
    BLUE = "blueberry"

allColors = {}

def countColors(colors: List[Color]):
    for c in colors:
        allColors[c] += 1

countColors([Color.RED, Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN])
for c in allColors:
    print(f"""{allColors[c]} {c.value} {c.name} pipes""")
```

When I run this, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mvce.py", line 18, in <module>
    countColors([Color.RED, Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN])
  File "mvce.py", line 16, in countColors
    allColors[c] += 1
KeyError: <Color.RED: 'cherry'>
```

The [documentation on dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) says that I can use any immutable value as a key, and I'd assume a enum value is immutable.

How can I use an enum as key in a dictionary?

Comment: `allColors[c] += 1` requires that `c` is an existed key. You may need an if condition.

Comment: You would have had the exact same problem with any other valid key type, like ints or strings.

Comment: @Sraw Yep, that was it. I assumed Python would create the directory entry automatically, like Perl does. Checking for it first and then either setting it to 0 or increasing it fixed the problem. If you want to post this as an answer I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: There's a library package called `defaultdict` that lets you define a dictionary with a default value to be returned instead of raising KeyError.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is failing because of two things:

1. += update expects to have the key already in the dictionary.

For this you will have to check if the dictionary has the key and if it doesn't *then* update the item

2. the access to the enum item like `allColors[c]` uses the `__get_item__` method for enums.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.EnumType.__getitem__

When you are trying to access, the variable c is an instance of Color but the method expects to match the *name* of the enum's member.

Changing this line

```py
    print(f"""{allColors[c]} {c.value} {c.name} pipes""")
```

to

```py
    print(f"""{allColors[c.name]} {c.value} {c.name} pipes""")
```

This is what I have at the end:

```py
from enum import Enum, unique
from typing import List

@unique
class Color(Enum):
    RED = "cherry"
    GREEN = "cucumber"
    BLUE = "blueberry"

allColors = dict()

def countColors(colors: List[Color]):
    for c in colors:
        if c in allColors.keys():
            allColors[c] += 1
        else:
            allColors.update({c:1})


countColors([Color.RED, Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN])
for c in allColors:
    print(f"""{allColors[c]} {c.value} {c.name} pipes""")
```

Answer (score -1):

Could it be that you have set 3 colors but in line 18 you have 4

```
countColors([Color.RED, Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN])
```

try

```
countColors ([Color.RED, Color.Blue, Color.Green])
```

Comment: Well, yes, I want to count how often I get each color, so that is on purpose.

Comment: Now I follow you Ethan.